# multiple nonblocking tasks using asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp

I am trying to perform several non blocking tasks with asyncio and aiohttp and I don't think the way I am doing it is efficient. I think it would be best to use await instead of yield. can anyone help?

```
def_init__(self):
    self.event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def run(self):
    tasks = [
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.subscribe()),
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.getServer()),]
    self.event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    try:
       self.event_loop.run_forever()

@asyncio.coroutine
def getServer(self):
    server = yield from self.event_loop.create_server(handler, ip, port)
    return server

@asyncio.coroutine
def sunbscribe(self):
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(10)
        self.sendNotification(self.sub.recieve())

def sendNotification(msg):
    # send message as a client
```

I have to listen to a server and subscribe to listen to broadcasts and depending on the broadcasted message POST to a different server.

Comment: Can you add the definition (or just the signature) of self.event_loop.create_server, is it also a coroutine?

Comment: its not a coroutine.  I'll add it to the code

Comment: Sorry, it is a coroutine:

Comment: coroutine AbstractEventLoop.create_server(protocol_factory, host=None, port=None, *, family=socket.AF_UNSPEC, flags=socket.AI_PASSIVE, sock=None, backlog=100, ssl=None, reuse_address=None, reuse_port=None)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression):

> await , similarly to yield from , suspends execution of read_data
>   coroutine until db.fetch awaitable completes and returns the result
>   data.
>
> **It uses the yield from implementation** with an extra step of validating
>   its argument. await only accepts an awaitable , which can be one of:

So I don't see an efficiency problem in your code, as they use the same implementation.

However, I do wonder why you return the `server` but never use it.

The main design mistake I see in your code is that you use both:

```
self.event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
try:
   self.event_loop.run_forever()
```

From what I can see you just need the `run_forever()`

Some extra tips:

In my implementations using asyncio I usually make sure that the loop is closed in case of error, or this can cause a massive leak depending on your app type.

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
finally:  # close the loop no matter what or you leak FDs
    loop.close()
```

I also use [Uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop) instead of the builtin one, according to benchmarks it's much more efficient.

```
import uvloop
...
    loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Comment: I am using aiohttp and have to Post to a server from a coroutine.  The example code for creating a client uses async.  how would I make a call to an async function?

Comment: Can you link to the example code? Maybe I'm wrong about not using a coroutine for the getServer.

Comment: this is the link to the client I am using http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html

Comment: Ok, I see, you need to create the server in the event loop indeed. However you can still delete the run_until_complete and just keep the run_forever.

Answer (score 0):

Await will not be more efficient than yield from.  It may be more pythonic, but

```
async def foo():
    await some_future
```

and

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def foo()
    yield from some_future
```

are approximately the same.  Certainly in terms of efficiency, they are very close.  Await is implemented using logic very similar to yield from.  (There's an additional method call to **await** involved, but that is typically lost in the noise)

In terms of efficiency, removing the explicit sleep and polling in your subscribe method seems like the primary target in this design.  Rather than sleeping for a fixed period of time it would be better to get a future that indicates when the receive call will succeed and only running subscribe's task when receive has data.

Comment: The implementation is the same so I don't think you are correct. As per the sleep I am not sure what you mean by " primary target in this design" but the point is to suspend the coroutine so it is a good thing.